# I want to know how to make this calculation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this algorithm but I am not sure I did the correct thing.

**Implement a calculation respecting the following rules (assume that the numbers received are positive integers greater than zero):**

- Calculates the sum of the numbers received as parameter.
- For each number that is a multiple of 3, add 1 to that number.

```js
 function calculator(numbers) {
        
            let sum=0;
            for(let num of numbers){
                if(num % 3 == 0) {
                    sum+=num + 1
                }
                else {
                    sum+=num;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        
        console.log(calculator([3,6,7,9,13,22,27]))
```

Comment: check your code,what are you returning from the function and what is supposed to return ?

Comment: yes this is what it is supposed to return, this is the boiler plate: function Calculator(numbers) { return 0; }

Comment: is it supposed to return 0 ?

Comment: yes it is supposed to return 0

Comment: maybe read the question again ?

Comment: @Bachir you specified the following 'Calculates the sum of the numbers received as parameter.' how is it supposed to return always 0 if you need to calculate the sum of the numbers. Doesn't make sense. You NEED to return the SUM of the numbers received as a parameter that meet the criteria.

Comment: yes, I realized after more reading and understood, that the 'return 0', is just a kind of trick, I was able to solve it thanks to everyone for all support

Answer (score 1):

```js
const nums = [3, 6, 7, 9, 13, 22, 27]

const calculator = (numbers) => {

  let sum = 0;
  for (let num of numbers) {
    if (num % 3 == 0) {
      num++
      sum += num; 
    }
    else {
      sum += num;
    }
  }
  return sum //you forgot to return your sum but rather you return always zero.
}

console.log(calculator(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like the following using ternary operator:

```js
const numbers = [3, 6, 7]

function calculate(arr){
  let total = 0
  for (let n of arr) {
    n % 3 === 0 ? total += n + 1 : total += n
  }
  return total
}

console.log(calculate(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

...and here's a one liner.

```js
const nums = [3, 6, 7, 9, 13, 22, 27];

let result = nums.reduce( ( sum, x ) => sum += x + ( x % 3 === 0 ), 0 );

console.log( result );
```